# To check whether given ring is principal ideal domain?

Tags: principal-ideal-domains

Is $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$ is principal ideal domain ?

no,

we know that polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is field iff $\mathbb{F}$ is field

here  $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not field.

consider ideal $\langle{x,2}\rangle$ which is not principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$ hence it is not PID.

please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Depending on context, you might be requred to explicitly _prove_ that $\langle x, 2\rangle$ is not principal, though.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is never a field.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$ is not a principal ideal domain because it is not even a domain.